# Chef template and using it in a loop

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

How to write this in a loop.
I am very new to ruby so struggling with the approach.

I am trying to create a response file and then update the fixpack for IHS (IBM HTTP Server)

```
    #Install the fix pack for IHS

template "/tmp/ihs-fixpack-response1.txt" do
  source "ihs-fixpack-response.erb"
  mode 0755
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  variables({
    :fixpack => "7.0.0-WS-IHS-LinuxX32-FP0000019.pak",
    :product_path => node[:websphere][:ihs][:ihs_path]
  })
end

# code for installing Fixpack
bash "ihs/was-updateinstaller" do
  user "root"
  code %(#{node[:websphere][:ihs][:ihs_updi_path]}/update.sh  -options "/tmp/ihs-fixpack-response1.txt" -silent)

end

#Install the fix pack for the plugin.
template "/tmp/ihs-fixpack-response2.txt" do
  source "ihs-fixpack-response.erb"
  mode 0755
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  variables({
    :fixpack => "7.0.0-WS-PLG-LinuxX32-FP0000019.pak",
    :product_path => node[:websphere][:ihs][:ihs_wasPluginPath]
  })
end

# code for installing Fixpack
bash "ihs/was-updateinstaller" do
  user "root"
  code %(#{node[:websphere][:ihs][:ihs_updi_path]}/update.sh  -options "/tmp/ihs-fixpack-response2.txt" -silent)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
[ [ "7.0.0-WS-IHS-LinuxX32-FP0000019.pak", node[:websphere][:ihs][:ihs_path] ],
  [ "7.0.0-WS-PLG-LinuxX32-FP0000019.pak", node[:websphere][:ihs][:ihs_wasPluginPath] ]
].zip(1..2).each do |vars, i|
  template "/tmp/ihs-fixpack-response#{i}.txt" do
    source "ihs-fixpack-response.erb"
    mode 0755
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    variables({
      :fixpack => vars.first,
      :product_path => vars.last
    })
  end

  bash "ihs/was-updateinstaller" do
    user "root"
    code %(#{node[:websphere][:ihs][:ihs_updi_path]}/update.sh  -options "/tmp/ihs-fixpack-response#{i}.txt" -silent)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. Its almost what i want.
I am trying to get new values for :fixpack and :product_path each time

if it was just a single value, its not a problem as i have seen expamples for the same. The problem is how to create a multiple dimention array. As in my case i have to populate the template with two different values on the runtime.

Or is there a better approach for this than the loop.

I can work with the single template "/tmp/ihs-fixpack-response.txt"

Thanks again for the help cbl

Comment: I have edited the answer to contemplate the `:fixpack` change. If that's still not what you need, try to tell specifically what's your desired outcome. :)